# Contains in Keyword Query Language SharePoint 2010

Tags: 2010, search-results, managed-property, kql

I have SharePoint 2010 list where items are stored names of cities. The field CityName is managed property. I compiled query using KQL with query text:

```
 query.QueryText = String.Format("CityName:\"*{0}*\", cityName);
```

I use

> *

for searching city by part of word. But when a try search Washington by

> wash

it is ok, but by

> ington

no results.

I did something wrong?

Comment: Look here: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/keyword-query-language-kql-syntax-reference. It seems that KQL does not support suffix matching, only prefix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per Microsoft, `"Prefix matching is also supported with phrases specified in property values, but you must use the wildcard operator (*) in the query, and it is supported only at the end of the phrase"`

So your 1st query works but not second

Reference link - [KQL](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/keyword-query-language-kql-syntax-reference)

*Look under header - 'Property values in the full-text index'*